# How add ETag header on JSON response in Laravel (Lumen)

Tags: php, laravel, etag, lumen

I have two routes:

```
$app->get('time1', function(){
    return response('time1 = '.time());
});
$app->get('time2', function(){
    return response()->json(['time2' => time()]);
});
```

And one global after-middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->setEtag(md5($response->getContent()));
    return $response;
}
```

In the first case I have this HTTP-header:

```
ETag:"8114ac3b0aad6e54345ee00f78959316"
```

But not in the second. Why? How to add the same header in the second case?

Comment: Are you sure you're missing the etag? I've run this code and got etag header in both cases

Comment: GET /time1
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 12:48:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Etag: "a6e2b39351fc075ac5bd9b8c078c35e8"
Expires: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 12:48:50 GMT

Comment: GET /time2
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 12:49:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Expires: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 12:49:58 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see no **ETag** in your second response is that this header is stripped by your web server due to the fact that the returned response is **compressed** by the server - see **Content-Encoding: gzip** header. The reasoning behind this is that the same resource cannot be byte-for-byte identical given that **gzip has various compression levels**.

You can either disable **gzip compression** (check your Apache config, especially config of mod_deflate module) or live without the **ETag**.

Comment: This problem is supposed to be solved by weak etags. [Nginx solves it by downgrading strong etags to weak etags](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/377#comment:14). Has Apache also implemented such a downgrade in the 3,5 years that has passed since this answer was written? Or is it still not possible to combine etag with gzip compression?

Comment: Er... what?! I mean, ETags are used to indicate that the *content* hasn't changed. And gzip is lossless compression, so the *content* is guaranteed to stay unchanged no matter what compression level is used. So I don't understand this reasoning, because the fact that the *gzipped* content is different is irrelevant for practical purposes. But maybe I'm missing something?!

Answer (score 1):

```
 ....    

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {

    $response = $next($request);

    if ($request->isMethod('GET'))
    {

        $etag = md5($response->getContent());

        $requestETag = str_replace('"', '', $request->getETags());



        if ($requestETag && $requestETag[0] == $etag)
        {

            // Modifies the response so that it conforms to the rules defined for a 304 status code.
            $response->setNotModified();

        }

        $response->setETag($etag);


    }

    return $response;

}
```